# Open Multiple Modals with Different Content - CSS & JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to open multiple modals on my page but I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to have each modal contain different content. I am new to javascript and modals so this was already a challenge but from looking up my question on here I found that maybe I need to learn another language like jQuery to achieve my goal?

If you could take a look at my code and help me out or stear my in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated!

HTML

```
<section class="section section-b">
<div class="container">
<h1>Workshops</h1>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div id="modalBtn" class="grid-box grid-box-a">
    <h3>Yoga Bootcamp</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="modalBtn" class="grid-box grid-box-b">
    <h3>Meditation</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="modalBtn" class="grid-box grid-box-c">
    <h3>Pregnancy</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="modalBtn" class="grid-box grid-box-d">
    <h3>Finding Gratitude</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="modalContainer" class="modal">
  <div class="modalContent">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h4>Yoga Bootcamp</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis totam iure ad, quasi vero blanditiis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="modalContainer" class="modal">
  <div class="modalContent">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h4>Meditation</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis totam iure ad, quasi vero blanditiis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="modalContainer" class="modal">
  <div class="modalContent">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h4>Pregnancy</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis totam iure ad, quasi vero blanditiis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="modalContainer" class="modal">
  <div class="modalContent">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h4>Finding Gratitude</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis totam iure ad, quasi vero blanditiis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var modal = document.getElementById('modalContainer');
var btn = document.getElementById('modalBtn');
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

I realize that right now I am only targeting the first div but I've tried to create a loop with no success and want to avoid just repeating the code for each div. Is what I'm trying to achieve possible with JS or would another language make more sense?

Comment: jQuery is not a language, but a JavaScript library.

Comment: You don't seem to have any actual modals in your example. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `id`s are supposed to be unique. You shouldn't assign the same id twice. This might already fix the issue you're seeing. If you need a shared value in a property, use `class`.

Comment: Viqas I'm not sure what you mean by I don't have any modals.

Comment: So right now when I select the div with grid-box-a, the first modalContainer opens. What I would like to do is when I select the next div, grid-box-b, it will open the second modalContainer

Comment: Changing the id to a class instead does not fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a [Unique ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) for each modal and add a click [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) to each button which triggers a specific modal to open. You can manually add the click event for each button or simply loop over them like I have done below. To achieve this in an automated way I have stored the id of each button's modal in a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) and selected groups of similar elements using [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('nav button');
let modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

function showModal(id) {
  let m = document.getElementById(id);
  m.classList.add('visible');
}

function hideModals() {
  modals.forEach(m => {
    m.classList.remove('visible');
  });
}

buttons.forEach(b => {
  b.addEventListener('click', event => {
    hideModals();
    showModal(b.dataset.modal);
  });
});

modals.forEach(m => {
  let x = m.querySelector('button.close');
  x.addEventListener('click', hideModals);
});
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

nav button {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  color: white;
}

.modal button.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button data-modal="yoga"> Yoga Bootcamp </button>
  <button data-modal="meditation"> Meditation </button>
  <button data-modal="pregnancy"> Pregnancy </button>
</nav>

<div class="modal" id="yoga">
  <button class="close">&times;</button>
  <h4>Yoga Bootcamp</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis totam iure ad, quasi vero blanditiis.</p>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="meditation">
  <button class="close">&times;</button>
  <h4>Meditation</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis totam iure ad, quasi vero blanditiis.</p>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="pregnancy">
  <button class="close">&times;</button>
  <h4>Pregnancy</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis totam iure ad, quasi vero blanditiis.</p>
</div>
```

By the way, I trimmed down the markup for this snippet and used more [semantic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics) elements to make it easier to see what is happening. I also included a smooth transition since that's just good practice as it makes for a better [user experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience).

Comment: Thank you! I was able to treek this a bit and get my desired outcome. Your code is very clean and simple. I think I was overcomplicating it!

Answer (score 0):

This [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pizylon/5wqc8z62/) could help. It's an example on a way to use the same modal with different title and content.(it uses jQuery and Bootstrap)

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Same modal different content</h2>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div  class="grid-box grid-box-a modal-toggle" data-title="First" data-content="First content." >
    <h4>First</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-box grid-box-b modal-toggle" data-title="Second" data-content="Second content.">
    <h4>Second</h4>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="mtitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" >
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".modal-toggle").click(function () {
        $('.modal-title').html($(this).data('title'));
         $('.modal-body').html($(this).data('content'));
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want tha if you press any button, it shows all the modals at the same time? if so, try using class intead of id, id must be unique for each element, change **id="modalBtn"** for **class="modalBtn"** and **var modal = document.getElementById('modalContainer')**; for  **var modal = document.getElementById('modal instead');**

But if you want first button to open first modal, try different ids for every button, and every modal.